# ggplot geom_line plot difficulties

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have follow-up data and would like to plot the medication use per subject. However, geom_line is not interrupting the line when there is a NA.

```
# A tibble: 23 × 3
      ID   day medication
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     
 1     1     1 NA        
 2     1     2 A         
 3     1     3 NA        
 4     1     4 A         
 5     1     5 A         
 6     1     5 B         
 7     1     6 A         
 8     2     1 NA        
 9     2     2 C         
10     2     3 NA        
11     3     1 A         
12     3     2 C         
13     3     2 D         
14     3     3 D         
15     3     4 NA        
16     3     5 A         
17     4     1 C         
18     4     1 D         
19     4     2 C         
20     4     2 D         
21     4     3 C         
22     4     3 D         
23     4     4 NA


k<-df%>% ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x=day, y= medication ,color= medication, group=medication),linewidth = 1,) +
  facet_grid(ID~ ., drop = TRUE, scales = "free", space = "free")
```

[image]

The plot in facet 3 still includes medication 3 at points it shouldn't.

I'm trying to get a graph where the top line indicates the follow-up (day) and all the lines below what medication was used on that day.

Comment: It is more like a data difficulty than a ggplot difficulty. If you could reformat you data into ` df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1,
  day_start = c(2, 4, 5, 6),
  day_end = c(2, 5, 5, 6),
  medication = c("A", "A", "B", "A")
)` for ID ==1 for example. Then you could use `geom_segment()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to reformat the data, as [Zhiqiang Wang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75564879/ggplot-geom-line-plot-difficulties#comment133317938_75564879) proposes.
Use `geom_segment` adjusting the x coordinates to fill unit segments representing days. The missing values are taken care of with `na.omit`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(na.omit(df1)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = day - 0.5, xend = day + 0.5, 
                   y = medication, yend = medication,
                color = medication), linewidth = 1) +
  facet_grid(ID~ ., drop = TRUE, scales = "free", space = "free")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>